# How to one-base-index with CSS?

Tags: javascript, function, math, css-tables, pseudo-element

I have an HTML table with 5 rows; each row has two cells (*title*, *main-content*).

I wanted to add `:before` automatic numbering to the rows with this CSS:

```
.view-my-book .views-field-title {counter-reset: item}
.view-my-book .views-field-title:before {content: counter(item) " ";
```

It works in the sense that each row is numbered

### My problem

The numbering starts from 0* (Zero-Based-Index) while I want to it to start from 1 (One Based Index / OBI); for example I have 5 rows 0-4.

### My question

How to one-base-index with CSS (assuming it is possible)?

Comment: What's the HTML? (for a [MCVE])

Comment: The HTML is created by a CMS; I don't know of a way to copy it directly from DOM (copy-paste in Chrome and AFAICR Firefox isn't effective and must be done per line, which is time wasting in this case).

Comment: Inspect the page, right click on the element you want to copy (maybe the whole body), copy innerHTML

Comment: I prefer not to copy all body.

Comment: @JohnDoea You dono't have to copy the whole body, just the relevant bits.

Comment: After almost a year and a half, I firmly edited this question to make it better but sadly I no longer have the HTML to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`counter-reset` alone resets a counter to 0, [as you can see in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset). If you want to set it to a different number, you can put a number after the counter name, for example:

```
.view-my-book .views-field-title {
  counter-reset: item 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexing of the counter all comes down to where you apply `counter-increment` (and to a lesser extent, `counter-reset`). If you want the numbers to start from `1`, all you need to do is increment the counter on `.views-field-title`:

```css
.view-my-book .views-field-title {
  counter-increment: item
}

.view-my-book .views-field-title:before {
  content: counter(item) " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="view-my-book">
  <div class="views-field-title">Text</div>
  <div class="views-field-title">Text</div>
  <div class="views-field-title">Text</div>
  <div class="views-field-title">Text</div>
</div>
```

And you can also reset the counter to a specific point if necessary, with `counter-reset: {counter} {count}` (such as `counter-increment: item 5`). You would want to apply this to the parent element -- `.view-my-book` in your case.

Here's an example of that:

```css
.view-my-book .views-field-title {
  counter-increment: item
}

.view-my-book .views-field-title:before {
  content: counter(item) " ";
}

.view-my-book {
  counter-reset: item 5
}
```

```html
<div class="view-my-book">
  <div class="views-field-title">Text</div>
  <div class="views-field-title">Text</div>
  <div class="views-field-title">Text</div>
  <div class="views-field-title">Text</div>
</div>
```